# RN42 Bluetooth Module - Entering command mode from C code

Tags: pic, uart, bluetooth

I am using a PIC32MX795F12 microcontroller together with a RN42 bluetooth to UART module.

I can send text to the UART with no problem at 115200 baud.
Using Putty I can also enter the command **$$$** to enter the command mode and get the **CMD** response.
Unfortunately I've not been able to enter the command mode using the C code.
My command to do this is as follows:

> "UART3WriteString("$$$");"

where the function is defined as:

```
void UART3WriteString(const char * str) {
while( *str ) {
    U3TXREG = *str++;
    while( U3STAbits.TRMT == 0 ); //wait for the transmission to be done)
}
```

}

When I do this, the RN42 does not go into the command mode. It just outputs $$$ without the CMD response.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you need CR and/or LF too? Try UART3WriteString("$$$\r\n")

Comment: I've tried that before. Actually in the putty as soon as you type the third '$' the CMD response comes up.